# Is promise.then asynchronous or not?

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, es6-promise

The following code hangs on Firefox and Chrome but not on Edge:

```
let sequence = Promise.resolve();
function fire() {
  sequence.then(fire)
};
fire();
```

I think it didn't hang on Firefox a few versions ago, I'm confused. What is the correct behavior here?

**Edit:** Edge 37.14316 now hangs too.

Comment: What is expected behavior , result ?

Comment: probably just an automatic weapon firing eternally

Comment: Btw, did you mean `sequence = sequence.then(fire)`?

Comment: @Bergi You're right but that doesn't matter in this specific example as the behavior is anyway different on browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hangs because `.then` chains execute on the microtask queue, unlike e.g. `setTimeout` which executes on the main JavaScript event queue:

```
let sequence = Promise.resolve();
function fire() {
  setTimeout(fire); // doesn't hang
};
fire();
```

Most browsers empty the microtask queue completely at the tail of the current run-to-completion, and your code prevents it from ever emptying, stalling the main JavaScript event queue.

The browser isn't totally hung, since users can stop this out-of-control script after a while. How usable the browser feels during this period depends on whether the browser supports multiple processes or not. E.g. Firefox Developer Edition fares better than Firefox here, since dev edition uses multiple processes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `Promise.then` is async, but when you resolve the promise right away, and then keep calling the same function inside the callback, you get an infinite loop, and the browser hangs

In simpler terms, you're doing

```
function fire() {
   fire(); // goes on forever
}
fire();
```

The only difference is `fire` is in an asynchronous callback that is already resolved, and fires right away.

If Edge doesn't hang, it's just because it can handle the recursion better.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it will indefinitely call `fire`, but it should not hang if promise callbacks runs asynchronously. I mean, it should be `fire->(a little time)->fire->(a little time)->fire->(... indefinite loop)`.

Comment: @KagamiSaschaRosylight: It is so, only that "*a little time*" is very, very short. Too short for anything else to run.

Comment: But what time, the promise is resolved, there's nothing to wait for? Best case, the browser checks the queue, which is empty, and fires `fire` again within nanoseconds

Comment: I thought running asynchronously is something like [setImmediate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate). Maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: Asynchronous doesn't mean the browser takes a ten minute coffee break before firing the function again, it just defers calling the function, adding it to the end of the queue, to allow the single thread it uses an opportunity to trigger anything else that may be waiting in the queue before triggering *that* function again. If there's nothing waiting in the queue, modern browsers can turn around amazingly fast and call the function again, and again, and again, creating an infinite loop

Comment: I would edit my comment: `fire->(a little time to repaint/call event listener if needed/etc)->fire->(repaint/call event listener if needed/etc)->fire->(... indefinite loop)`. Maybe Firefox/Chrome just skip them and Edge does not.

Comment: Yes, it does that, but *"a little time"*, is as Bergi said, so little that it effectively overwhelmes the browser with so many calls to `fire()` that the UI freezes up.

Answer (score 1):

The correct behaviour is to hang<sup>1</sup>. You won't get a stack overflow, but asynchronous infinite recursion is still infinite recursion.

<sub>1: It's an endless loop in the microtask queue. Other promise jobs might get to run, but not much else.</sub>